# How to hide the menu item of context menu in wpf xaml based on condition

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, mvvm

In my xaml, I have used wpf ContextMenu to display the menu items in wpf datagid. I need to hide the menu items based on the condition. I tried the following but its not working.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenuTextCell">


            <MenuItem Name="copyDealContextMenu"
                    Header="Copy Deal"
                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.CopyDeal}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{ Binding ElementName= BlotGrid,Path=DataContext.ProductType }" Value="FXO">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

            </MenuItem>

        </ContextMenu>
```

How to hide the menu items in context menu?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing your command binding isn't working also..

Comment: Command binding is working fine. Just added a style to control the visibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 reason this did not work.

1) is that ContextMenu does not reside in the same VisualTree as the element it is set for ( i.e. it's PlacementTarget). There for you would not be able to bind to an element with **ElementName**.

2) you put your Style like it's a Content of the MenuItem. ( I didn't notice it at first as well..). it needs to be set to the DependencyProperty 'Style' of your MenuItem.

```
<Grid x:Name="BlotGrid" Background="Red">
     <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>            
            <MenuItem Name="copyDealContextMenu"
                Header="Copy Deal"        
                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                 <MenuItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu},Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.IsXXX}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>      
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Eran, ContextMenu is a part of Grid. ContextMenu will appear on datagrid by right clicking on the row. Tried the above code, able to see the PlacementTarget.DataContext.ProductType in Xaml as expected but style datatrigger is not getting triggered as I am not able to see the menu item

Comment: check your code i did it with a IsXXX property . and a True value .
did you change it to accomedate your need code. 

btw . i tested it before posting the answer.so keep an open mind and check your self. the reasons i stated are valid.

Comment: ' <MenuItem.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid},Path=DataContext.ProductType}" Value="FXO">
                          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
         </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.Style>
'

Comment: Above code worked for me. Thanks Eran for the direction.

Comment: you should add it to your question.